# ubuntu 14.04 wont recognize windows 8.1

Tags: windows, 14.04

when I boot ubuntu 14.04 off a usb/DVD to install it wont recognize windows 8.1 and only says " erase disk and install ubuntu ". this is the ubuntu that will work with my laptop. i do not want to get rid of windows 8 and the recovery partition because it will be like throwing $200 down the drain.

Comment: Hi new user, please read the marked question, especially the part about having at least 1 free primary partition. If you don't have at least one you will get the "error" about erasing the disk and installing Ubuntu only. So make sure you have some space left on a freed primary partition so Ubuntu can be installed alongside Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to partition the drive before you install Ubuntu. I unfortunately made the mistake once and wiped my entire hard drive. I highly recommend from personal experience that you get gparted or use the built in partitioner in the Ubuntu install usb to partition at least 15GB for Ubuntu. Do a Google search for "Dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows" to find explanations more in-depth than I could tell you.
Here is a good guide on how to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows.
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create a new separate partition and install ubuntu in that partition

you can install in seperate partition by selecting "something else" during installation and selecting your new partition where you want to install Ubuntu